# Delete ROW from MYSQL database without having a Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key, sql-delete

How can I delete one row from my database, without having a column that has unique input for each line?
Example:

```
    Surname     Name         Age

    Mark        Oswell       12
    Adrian      Peterson     15
    Mark        Penda        18
    July        Peterson     12
```

The basic way you do this is:

```
DELETE FROM ____ WHERE ____
```

If I delete `WHERE surname = Mark`, I won't be deleting just 1 row, but 2. Best way to solve this is with a Primary Key, but I can't use it (Long story, don't ask why :) ). So I need another way to solve this.

Is there any way to be able to delete the number of a row?

As an example, let's say I want to delete the row with `Mark Penda 18`. Can I do something like :

```
DELETE FROM ____ WHERE row = 3
```

Comment: Is this your real world example, or is this just a hypothetical? Deleting the first row with the `surname` "Mark"  seems pretty arbitrary. Age also seems irrelevant over time.

Comment: `Why the "hello" from the beginning of all my Stackoverflow questions gets deleted everytime ?` Because it's the network preference: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Ok, thx for leting me now.

Comment: Btw Barns, I know is arbitrary, it was just an example so I can stat my question, I know it is arbitrary, bcs 10 ppl can be named Mark. Thx for the interest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Database tables are unsorted sets. A row doesn't have an intrinsic number.

What you could do, however, is just have conditions on all the columns. And if you want to be extra-sure you're only deleting one row, add a `limit` cluase:

```
DELETE FROM mytable
WHERE       name = 'Mark' AND surename = 'Oswell' AND age = 12
LIMIT       1
```

Comment: Didn't knew about the LIMIT 1 thing, let me try it, gona come back with feedback

Answer (score 0):

Just Make like this:

```
delete from my_table where name in ('Oswell')
```